# Symfony: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine, connection

I've seen that this question has been asked a million times and I tried to apply every suggested solution I could find. I still get the error message "access denied".

I'm on a MacBook using the MySqlWorkbench to setup my database. Initially I wanted the following parameters:

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: starpartners
database_user: starpartners
database_password: "******"
```

but when I try to set up the database with user "star partners" and port "8000" I just get an error saying:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:8000 with user starpartners
>   Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60

For system error 60 I wasn't able to find anything on the web..

So I changed the port to the default "3306" and the username to "root" which at least helped me setting up the database.

But when I then go back to my project and e.g. try to flush the db or clear the cache or access my project I keep getting the error.

As you can see, my password is surrounded by quotation marks, the parameters are located in the parameters.yml file.

My MySql server has the status running, so that can't be the problem either.

Do you need any further information? Do you have any suggestions where I could look for a solution?

Comment: Have you checked which port mysql process is listening?

Comment: Can you actually login with parameters used abve from CLI? Example: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u starpartners -p starpartners`?

Comment: @TheOni my mysql server is running on the 3306 port

Comment: @JovanPerovic sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you mean! where should I try this?
EDIT: sorry just tried it on the command line, get the same "access denied" error

Comment: Are you running your development environment in a VM, docker, or directly on your macbook ?

Comment: @Mcsky I'm running it directly on my MacBook! :)

Comment: Humm give a try to `select host, user, password from mysql.user;` as root user. Find the row corresponding to your user and please check the value of the host column

Comment: Have you granted the right privileges for the user starpartners so to grant access to your database?

Comment: @sonja Since you’re running this on Mac, that would be the Terminal

Comment: @Mcsky Ii get the error 

Error Code: 29. File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: @TheOni when I let me show all privileges, it says GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES, so I guess that's fine..

Comment: @JovanPerovic I know I meant Terminal, I did it on my terminal but got the same "access denied error" :/

Comment: @sonja Aha, well, that's good - it means that has nothing to do with Symfony/PHP/Doctrine. Make sure that you GRANT line says `starpartners@127.0.0.1` and not `starpartners@localhost` - I've seen some cases of this failing...

Comment: @JovanPerovic Hm but somehow I'm not able to set up a database connection with my user called starpartners. only root is working!

Comment: Can you share that table record with us here? Redact anything that might be confidential, of course...

Comment: @JovanPerovic sorry for asking stupid again. which table record do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162045/discussion-between-jovan-perovic-and-sonja).

Comment: Have you checked your Mac Firewall? Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and then check the Firewall tab. For quick testing you can just disable it, but you might want to unlock and check the firewall options to see if a rule is set up to block the mysql connection.